# Scaling Postgres database to handle parallel requests

Tags: database, multithreading, postgresql, parallel-processing, scaling

I am using Postgres Database as primary database with Rails application. Currently the configuration for the database is: CPU - **8 cores**, RAM - **32 GB**, hosted on AWS. However I need to scale this server as I am facing a lot of serious bottlenecks.

I need to be able to handle 10000 parallel requests to this server. Even if this is not achievable I at-least need to know what would be the maximum number that this database can handle. The requests includes complex **SELECT** and **UPDATE** queries.

I have changed settings such as **max_connections** to **10000** and in the `rails_config/database.yml` the **connection_pool** is set to **10000**.

I am running a rails code which currently runs in 50 parallel threads. The code runs fine for a while until I receive this error:
`PG::ConnectionBad: PQsocket() can't get socket descriptor`. After this when I log into the postgres server and try to execute something, I get this:

```
db_production=# select id from product_tbl limit 5;
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Succeeded.
db_production=#
```

After this restarting the rails code also works fine but only for a while until I again receive the same error.
I looked at the CPU usage while the threads are running. Some observations:

- One SELECT query uses all the CPU (shows 100% usage) for one core, the rest are sitting idle at 0%. This can be inferred because when only one process or query is running, only one CPU shows 95-100% usage. **Does this mean I will only be able to run 8 queries or threads in parallel as there are only 8 cores?**
- RAM is kept underutilized. Even when 7 out of 8 queries or threads are running in parallel, the RAM used is only around 3 GB. **Can I somehow increase this and accommodate more parallel queries?**
- For every running thread, this is the configuration: **virtual memory usage->751M**, **resident memory usage->154-158M**, **shared memory used->149-150M**, **CPU%->60-100%**, **MEM%->0.5-0.6%**. Is everything right here or I need to tweak some settings to make use of the resources more effectively?

What are the configuration settings I need to change in order to scale the database? What must be the ideal number of threads such that I at-least don't receive the connection error? What are the checks and steps to scale the database to handle large parallel connections? How can I make full use of the available resources?

Comment: Look at http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/ and use those settings as a starting point. And don't set max_connections that high, you want to use a connection pool with postgres, and set it to a few hundred at most.

Comment: the link is great!!! But why should the max_connections not be set that high? I need to arrive at 10000 parallel connections with the database. Is 9999 the maximum parallel I can achieve with one server?

Comment: Postgres connections are expensive, in pretty much all real applications you use a connection pool that recycles a smaller number of real Postgres connections. I'd try something around 100 or 200 first, and then see how good the performance is. Your actual number of parallel queries can be higher because you're using a connection pool. Each real Postgres connection also uses RAM, you can quickly run out of RAM with too many connections.

Comment: **actual number of parallel queries can be higher than max_connections**. This means that connection pool < max_connections. How much should the connection pool be?